# Add auto incremented values to scala map for null values

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have Scala map like below:

```
val mapData = Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> null, AA4 -> null)
```

I want to auto increment the value from highest map value(in above map it is "2").

```
val maxValue = mapData.valuesIterator.max
```

I want to iterate through this map and if the value is `null` substitute the value with the auto incremented value starting from highest map value(in above map it is `2`). Result should be like below. Order is not important.

```
Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 3, AA4 -> 4)
```

I tried using `mapData.map()` but I couldn't persist the incremented value during the map operation. Is there any other way in Scala to achieve this?

Comment: What should happen if you have `val mapData = Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> null, AA4 -> null, AA5 -> 5)`? In addition, you are saying _Order is not important_, is `Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 4, AA4 -> 3)` a valid response? If not, order does matters.

Comment: Yes "Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 4, AA4 -> 3)" is a valid response. If the input is "val mapData = Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> null, AA4 -> null, AA5 -> 5)" then results can be "Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 6, AA4 -> 7, AA5 -> 5)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code snippet you provided won't compile, because of `Null` in values and keys not swapped in quotes to be considered as string. I've replaced values with `Option`:

```
val mapData: Map[String, Option[Int]] = Map("AA1" -> Some(1), "AA2" -> Some(2), "AA3" -> None, "AA4" -> None)

val max = mapData.values.flatten.max
val (result, _) = mapData.toList.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int] -> (max + 1)) {
  case ((accumulator, nextMax), (key, None)) =>
    ((accumulator + (key -> nextMax)), nextMax + 1)
  case ((accumulator, nextMax), (key, Some(value))) =>
    ((accumulator + (key -> value)), nextMax)
}

println(result)
```

which will print next result: `Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 3, AA4 -> 4)`
Scatie example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ltmhh3tuQCWf2deaLboK9w

UPDATE:
As @Tomer Shetah correctly stated in comments section - `max` is not safe, because `List[Int].empty.max` will throw exception. Replaced with `maxOption`

```
val mapData: Map[String, Option[Int]] = Map("AA1" -> Some(1), "AA2" -> Some(2), "AA3" -> None, "AA4" -> None)

val max = mapData.values.flatten.maxOption.getOrElse(0) //safer with maxOption
val (result, _) = mapData.toList.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int] -> (max + 1)) {
  case ((accumulator, nextMax), (key, None)) =>
    ((accumulator + (key -> nextMax)), nextMax + 1)
  case ((accumulator, nextMax), (key, Some(value))) =>
    ((accumulator + (key -> value)), nextMax)
}

println(result)
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iiSvahIZStyL1MDi0Glsvg

Comment: Notice what happens to your output if you include `"AA5"`, `"AA6"`, and `"AA7"` in `mapData`.

Comment: @jwvh Excuse, Could you please elaborate - I added these cases, but so far can't figure out what's wrong. Question author stated `Order is not important.` though

Comment: And it's a good thing that _"order is not important"_ because a `Map`, by definition, has no order. But what does the OP mean by that? Does it mean the order of presentation is unimportant (i.e. `AA5->5, AA2->2,`... etc. is OK)? Or does it mean that the order of incrementing is unimportant (i.e. `AA3->7,  AA5->4,`... etc.)? The requirements are unclear.

Comment: @Mohan Could you elaborate on requirements, please?

Comment: @jwvh thank you very much details.  Yes I agree requirements unclear, so I've tried to prepare answer based on some assumptions.

Comment: I mentioned "Order is not important" as like below. result can be "AA3 -> 3, AA4 -> 4" or "AA3 -> 4, AA4 -> 3". Order is not important for keys for which incremented values are newly added when it have null values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic approach but might not a optimized one.

```
var mapData = Map("AA1" -> 1, "AA2" -> 2, "AA3" -> null, "AA4" -> null)

 val nonNull = mapData.values.filter(_ != null)
 val max = nonNull.map(_.toString.toInt).max
 var nullCount = mapData.count(_._2==null)

 mapData=mapData.map(t => {
 if (t._2 == null) {
    val output = (t._1, max + nullCount)
    nullCount -= 1
    output
}
else (t._1, t._2)
})
println(mapData)
   
//output : Map(AA1 -> 1, AA2 -> 2, AA3 -> 4, AA4 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is:

```
val startFrom = mapData.values.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).map(_.asInstanceOf[Int]).maxOption.getOrElse(0) + 1
val values = LazyList.from(startFrom).iterator
val result = mapData.view.mapValues {
  case x: Int => x
  case null => values.next()
  case _ => ???
}
```

Please note that `result` is not materialized. You need to call `.toMap` to materialize it.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/594wGKZaS5KflTHfiQLUfA)